# Iterate through folders that start with the same name

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to iterate through multiple folders and do something with the mp4 files in them, in one `for` loop. The folder names are formatted like this:

```
Book 1; Water
Book 2; Earth
Book 3; Fire
```

So far I'm going through them manually:

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in ("Book 1; Water\*.mp4") do (
    echo %%~ni
)
for /r %%i in ("Book 2; Earth\*.mp4") do (
    echo %%~ni
)
for /r %%i in ("Book 3; Fire\*.mp4") do (
    echo %%~ni
)
PAUSE
```

I prefer a method that reads out `Book*\*.mp4` in one go. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN ("Book*") DO (
 FOR %%b IN ("%%a\*mp4") DO ECHO %%b
)
```

should produce your list of files - `sourcedir` contains your starting directoryname.